# set positional parameters in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am new to learning hibernate and MYSQL. Can i set positional parameters values for select query. 
For example like

```
Session sess = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
SQLQuery sqlquery1 = sess.createSQLQuery("select price from prices where sku=:s and competitorId=:c");

    sqlquery1.setString("s","skulist.get(i)");
    sqlquery1.setInteger("c", 1);
    sqlquery1.executeUpdate();
```

If this approach is wrong, how can i set values to select query.Please help me solve my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of sku parameter then it should be

```
sqlquery1.setString("s",skulist.get(i));
```